# ERROR ITMS-90046 when trying to submit binary, using pods with use_frameworks

Tags: ios, cocoapods, submission

I am generating the release ipa using xcodebuild on command line(archive, export archive).
When uploading the binary using Application Loader I get the following error:

```
ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application 
bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not 
supported on iOS. Specifically, value 'xyzabc.com.mycompany.companyapp' for
key 'application-identifier' in 'Payload/myapp.app/Frameworks/Mixpanel.framework/Mixpanel' is not supported. This value should be a string starting with your TEAMID, 
followed by a dot '.', followed by the bundle identifier."
```

I have seen similar questions but workarounds but those have not worked for me.
Any help is appreciated.
Thx

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by using fastlane/gym.